# PhoneGap Screenshot plugin not working for Android?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am currently used screenshot plugin (plugin version 2.0.0) for phonegap android project that plugin returns some error like

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'saveScreenshot' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html

Mycode:

```
 <script src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/Screenshot.js"></script>
 <script>
  document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
   $('#screen').click(function(){
   window.plugins.screenshot.saveScreenshot();
  });
 } 
</script>

 <button id="screen">ScreenSave</button>
```

what i am doing wrong anyone guide me.
Thanks

**EDIT**

---

### Config.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <cordova>
      <!--
        access elements control the Android whitelist.
        Domains are assumed blocked unless set otherwise
         -->

      <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
      <!-- allow local pages -->

      <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
      <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
      <access origin=".*"/>

      <!-- <content src="http://mysite.com/myapp.html" /> for external pages -->
      <content src="index.html" />
      <log level="DEBUG"/>
      <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
      <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
      <plugins>
        <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
        <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
        <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
        <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
        <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
        <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
        <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
        <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
        <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
        <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
        <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
        <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
        <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
        <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
        <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
        <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
        <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />
        <plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
        <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
        <plugin name="Screenshot" value="org.apache.cordova.Screenshot"/>
      </plugins>
    </cordova>
```

**EDIT-2**
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: can you post your config.xml here?

Comment: @Whizkid747  now i update my config.xml

Comment: it seems good ... have you checked the LogCat ?

Comment: @DanteSparda yes i checked i got  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'saveScreenshot' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Quite a bit of things are missing here. You need to Add the [screenshot.java](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Screenshot/v2.0.0/src/org/apache/cordova) file to your project and add reference to [screenshot.js](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Screenshot/v2.0.0/www) in your index.html. Also you need to provide permission to write to local storage as [described here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Screenshot/).